# Cant override styles of nested Material UI components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the card and cardContent component of material ui. I have both in functional components and am trying to override the root style of each. however, I cant figure out how to modify the css of the cardContent component. It seems like that by modifying the root style of card. it wont let me modify the root style of cardcomponent. instead my css shows up in the inspector as being in

```
.jss14 {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

rather than being in the `.MuiCardContent-root`

Is there something i am missing with using makeStyles?

my attempt

```
import React from "react"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"

import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent"

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    flexDirection: "column",
    height: "100%",
    padding: 0,
  },
})

export default function AccountCardContent(props) {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return <CardContent className={classes.root}> {props.children}</CardContent>
}
```

```
import React from "react"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card"

import AccountCardContent from "../AccountCardContent"

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: "324px",
    height: "194px",
    borderRadius: "8px",
  },
})

export default function AccountCard({ icon, title, description, onClick }) {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root} onClick={onClick}>
      <AccountCardContent>asdf</AccountCardContent>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

Comment: Also, you can choose your own name, you don't have to name it `root`.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out hotpink! So in your example when i use the inspector, your hotpink cardContent didn't override the default `padding-bottom: 24px`. And this is my problem exactly. I dont understand how i can override this default.

Comment: Ah, I see, I simply added a background color to prove my point instead of checking your individual declarations. I'll make it a proper answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct for the most part and your problem is not related to MUI or React, but [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child). You are trying to overwrite

```css
.MuiCardContent-root:last-child
```

and the added pseudo class results in a higher specificity than your `.jss14` (`makeStyles-root-14` in development) class. Ideally you always mimic the selector you are trying to overwrite, in this case:

```js
  root: {
    // other styles
    "&:last-child": {
      paddingBottom: 0
    }
  }
```

and in case of doubt, you can simply increase specificity step by step by adding additional `&` to your selector until it works:

```js
  root: {
    // other styles
    "&&": {
      paddingBottom: 0
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically, the Material UI components accepts a `classes` prop that can be used to override its styles.

Please check it out [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/)

So you can this:

```
<Card
  classes={{
    root: classes.root, // class name, e.g. `classes-nesting-root-x`
  }}
>
```

Comment: As long as you are only targeting `root` and not nested children `className` works fine, as stated in the link you provided.